# IntelliJ how to map keyboard shortcut to new "template"

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

For Grails i want to map the textmate shortcuts I already know in the gsp files:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> should map into

```
> <% | %>
```

and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> should map into

```
> <%= |`enter code here` %>
```

Where the caret "|" represents position of the cursor.

I would expect this to be possible when I select "Tools"> "Save as Live Template". But i cannot find out how to use a keyboard shortcut with that command.

Perhaps I overlook some thing that actually already exists elswhere in Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to assign keyboard shortcuts to the live templates, they are expanded using abbreviation and <kbd>Tab</kbd> by default. You can try to create a **Macro** with the abbreviation and <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then assign a keyboard shortcut to this macro.